# Disadvantages of dynamically including CSS/JS files?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, include

What are the specific disadvantages (if any) of dynamically including the CSS and JS files for a website?

By dynamically, I mean, using the document.write() method generate  and  tags.

I'd like to use this technique on a very large, high-traffic website, since it allows me to easily manage which files are downloaded for which site sections, and to switch on a compressed mode in which only minified files are downloaded.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Reliability. People may have JS
   disabled, etc.
2. Debugging. Some browsers (IE) don't
   give you the included file's line
   number on an error, but simply the
   `document.write` line in the main file.

Comment: Good points. Although regarding point 1, reliability of Javascript wouldn't be affected, only CSS. If we assume that all our users have Javascript turned on, I don't believe it would matter whether we used the dynamic or traditional method.

Answer (score 2):

The advantages are that you can manage and organize your code more easily and you're able to load only those scripts on the page that are absolutely necessary.

The disadvantage, one that I can think of, is that some website performance measuring tools such as [PageSpeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) and [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) will warn you about the number of CSS and JavaScript files referenced by a page. Modern web development practices often encourage you to *Combine CSS files* and *Combine JavaScript files* to reduce the total number of files required to render a page and improve network performance. Generally speaking, serving one big, bloated file is better than serving 10 small lean-and-mean files because of the overhead associated with requesting a file from the server.